# GKE metrics comparsion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Does anyone know how can I compare my query result to some value?
For example, I have such query:

```
fetch k8s_container
| { metric 'kubernetes.io/container/cpu/core_usage_time'
| filter
    (metadata.user_labels.project =~ '.*')
| align rate(1m)
| every 1m
| group_by [resource.container_name],[value_core_usage_time_aggregate: aggregate(value.core_usage_time)];
metric 'kubernetes.io/container/cpu/limit_cores'
| filter
    (metadata.user_labels.project =~ '.*')
| group_by 1m, [value_limit_cores_mean: mean(value.limit_cores)]
| every 1m }
| outer_join 0
| div
```

And I want to get only those result that bigger than 0.5. How can I do it?

Using PromQL it's easy, like

```
some_metric/other_metric > 0.5
```

Or even boolean result

```
some_metric/other_metric > 0.5
```

This query returns 0 or 1.

But with GKE metrics it isn't easy at all

Comment: For that purpose in GCP, you can use the alerting operation `condition` in Google Cloud Monitoring. Some examples are available in the public document [Monitoring Query Language reference - Alerting](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#alerting-group). With this, you can obtain a `Bool` column, with a value depending if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolve the issue with the next query

```
fetch k8s_node
| { 
    t_0:
    metric 'kubernetes.io/node/ephemeral_storage/used_bytes'
    | group_by 1m, [value_used_bytes_mean: mean(value.used_bytes)]
    | every 1m
    ; t_1:
    metric 'kubernetes.io/node/ephemeral_storage/total_bytes'
    | group_by 1m, [value_total_bytes_mean: mean(value.total_bytes)]
    | every 1m
}
| outer_join 0
| value val(0)/val(1)
| map rename[node : resource.node_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like the [gt](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#gt-func) function.

It should be as simple as using gt(val()).